# Send AJAX request before Get request rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am sending `GET` request with javascript window.open method and I need to pass array of some ids in it. So when I get URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/controller_path/new?ids[]=1025&ids[]=1027
```

But this is not acceptable. URL should not look like this. And I can't send the parameters through `POST` because my team lead denied it.

I wonder can I send an ajax request before my main `GET` request and pass array of `ids` with it, store it someway in my "new" method and use them when `GET` request is being sent? If it is possible how can I do this in rails? I other words I need to send my array with ajax request, store it somehow and use it when my actual `GET` request is sent. Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize the data using JSON.

So if you have:

```
var ids = [9,4,5,8];
```

You can use this:

```
var getString = "?ids="+JSON.stringify(ids);
var filePath = "whereYouAreSending";
window.open(filePath+getString);
```

Comment: This would make the url like `"http://localhost:3000/controller_path/new?ids=[9,4,5,8]"` And you should uri encode it and it will end up like `"http://localhost:3000/controller_path/new?ids=%5B9%2C4%2C5%2C8%5D"`

Comment: It is not a solution but it makes URL look better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

define a [route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) with a controller method to handle the data